# Ignoring GET error of an unexisting webpage

Tags: perl, get, www-mechanize

I use `WWW::Mechanize` to fetch and process web pages. I have a piece of code, which looping through a list of web pages. It looks approximately like this:

```
while (<$readFileHandle>) {
    $mech->get("$url");
}
```

Now the problem occurs when one of the web pages in the list does not exist for some reason(which is ok). The issue is that in this case - the program returns an error and exits. The error looks like that:

```
Error GETing <url> Not Found at <PATH/file.pl> line ...
```

How can I ignore such type of error? I want the program just keep running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `eval {};` for this:

```
while ( my $url = readline($readFileHandle) ) {
    chomp $url;
    eval {
        $mech->get($url);
    };
    if ($@) {
      #error processing code
    }
}
```